# Did AWS just drop supporting Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

I have a couple of EC2 instances running with **Ubuntu 12.04LTS**. My ssh session into one of them suddenly stopped and I couldn't get back on. I tried rebooting the instance, trying to ssh into another one of the running instance but on luck. Then I tried ssh'ing into both the instances from another machine. Still it couldn't connect. Then, I tried firing up a new instance right now and the AMIs list does not show Ubuntu 12.04LTS or Ubuntu 13.10 anymore. Instead it seemed to have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04LTS (PV). I'm not sure why that would effect me ssh-ing into the instance. Anyway, I tried ssh'ing into the newly created instance and same issue.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: so you are unable to access any instance that you create? are the security groups properly configured?

Comment: what's the ssh failure?

Comment: works fine here. also, LTS should mean support until 2017 (from Canonical not AWS, but still).

Comment: I'm also having a similar problem.  Everything was fine using 12.04, but now that I've been forced to 14.04 (short of creating my own image), it is not working so well.  More often than not the new instances fail status checks and I can't SSH into them.  I keep bouncing them until I finally get one that passes status checks and then I can SSH in.  I see the following error in the log: Tpmfront:Error Unable to read device/vtpm/0/backend-id during tpmfront initialization! error = ENOENT

Comment: I posted in the AWS forum and they asked me for an example instance id which I have provided. They also pointed out that working instances also have the error I mentioned above.  I checked a working instance I had from last month and it does contain the same error so I guess that is not a factor.

Comment: Just found out that the problem I'm experiencing seems to be limited to t1.micro instances.  It worked fine with an m1.small instance.  Are  you using t1.micro and, if so, can you try it with a larger instance?

Comment: you can still start ubuntu 12.04, just go to marketplace and search for it.